# Query object including aggregate count data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a somewhat basic table for an admin to view users, how many users they've invited and how many of those users have paid for their subscription. The slimmed down tables look like this:

```
User: id, email
Referral: id, inviter_id <- (maps to user_id), paid_at (date, is either nil or set)
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to aggregate the data, then do the sorting, then pagination before returning the set to the view. I want to have the full user object if possible, although I'd settle for just the fields I need if that's not possible.

I've been trying to rework the following:

`User.joins(:referrals).group('users.id').count('referrals.id')`

This returns me a hash of `{ id: count }`. How can I also obtain the results when `paid_at IS NOT NULL` and even get these as key value pairs? I've been trying joins but am at a loss for how to do this properly, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've also tried this query:

```
User.joins(:referrals).select('users.id, users.email, count(referrals.id)').group('users.id, users.email')
```

However it only returns the id and email, I'm assuming because the ActiveRecord model doesn't have a field for referrals_count.

EDIT: Added SQL

```
  SELECT
    users.id,
    users.email,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(r1.id)) AS referrals_count, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(r2.id)) AS paid_referrals_count
  FROM
    users
  LEFT JOIN
    referrals AS r1 ON users.id = r1.inviter_id AND
    r1.accept_at IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN
    referrals AS r2 ON r1.id = r2.id AND
    r2.paid_at IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    users.id, users.email
  ORDER BY
    paid_referrals_count
```

I'm not sure if the above sql works, it was a first pass of what the data I was trying to obtain.

Comment: Share your SQL query, to "translate" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm assuming because the ActiveRecord model doesn't have a field for referrals_count." You are right. Use `AS paid_referrals_count` in your select.

`User.joins(:referrals).select('users.id, users.email, count(referrals.id) AS paid_referrals_count').group('users.id, users.email')`

Comment: On initial testing this seems to be working, even though that field wasn't showing up in the REPL. Going to apply it to the table and make sure it's polling accurately, then will accept. Thanks!